# Frames not getting updated automatically in scikit video output

Tags: scikit-image

I am using a code similar to this

```
from skvideo.io import VideoCapture
cap = VideoCapture(filename)
cap.open()

while True:
retval, image = cap.read()

# image is a numpy array containing the next frame
# do something with image here
plt.show()
if not retval:
    break
```

However the output only displays one frame and the second frame is displayed only after I close the first frame. Is there any function in scikit similar to cv2.waitKey() and cv2.destroyAllWindows() to update the frames automatically?

Comment: This is not a scikit-image question.

Answer (score 1):

Try indenting the code properly, as below:

```
 from skvideo.io import VideoCapture
 cap = VideoCapture(filename)
 cap.open()

 while True:
    retval, image = cap.read()

    # image is a numpy array containing the next frame
    # do something with image here
    plt.show()
    if not retval:
        break
```